# Css navigation bar (css&html) issue

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

So, i have this navigation bar:

[image: Nav bar without borders]

I want to put a border around it, but it becomes bigger, which i do not like:

[image: Nav bar with borders]

I try to set height of the navigation bar, but the links do not fit in anymore, and there's no way to put them back in:

[image: Nav bar with height set]

Please help.

Code(CSS):

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    //font-family: lkth;
    border: double;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #663D07;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}
#navLi {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.navA {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Code(HTML):

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navUl">
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#"><p>Page d'accueil</p></a></li>
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#"><p>Evénements</p></a></li>
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#"><p>Contactez nous</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I get this if i display navLi as block and Navigation as inline-block:
[image]

Comment: If you display #navLi as a block and #navigation as a inline-block, what result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#navigation` but you could also try using `margin:-5px;`. I fixed the semantics of your example and added `margin:-5px` to it. Hope this helps.

```css
#navigation {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  //font-family: lkth;
  border: double;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #663D07;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 40px;  
  list-style-type:none;
}
#navigation  ul {
  margin:-5px;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;  
}
#navigation a {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Page d'accueil</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Evénements</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Contactez nous</p></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I wonder though, why did the links not get back in when i  tried to put margin-bottom for the li elements.

Comment: Ah that's probably because you needed to use margin-top instead. However it's just easier to correct margin as a whole to make it easier to position elements later on :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the navigation. This way border should not add up to the block dimensions.

```css
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /* font-family: lkth; */
    border: double;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #663D07;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Does not work, the links just get farther down from the navigation bar.

Comment: Then check jaunt's answer with additional margin tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code edited:

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: double;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #663D07;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}
#navUl{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 500px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 }
#navLi {
   display: inline-block; 
   height: 40px;  
}

<div id="navigation">
   <ul id="navUl">
       <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#">Page d'accueil</a></li>
       <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#">Evénements</a></li>
       <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#">Contactez nous</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```css
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    //font-family: lkth;
    border: double;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #663D07;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;

}
#navigation li {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 10px;

}
#navigation a {
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navUl">
        <li><a href="#">Page d'accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Evénement</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contactez nous</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can target your li and a in your navigation directly, you don't need to specify classes for that. I added list-style: none, because you don't want your list with bullets. Also replaced display: inline-block with float: left, which basically does the same thing. The margin is a shorthand for margin-top: 0px, margin-right: 10px, margin-bottom: 0px and margin-left: 0px;

As a last touch, the line-height: 10px; this lines your links out more in the middle.

Also a small note, id's can't be used more than once! An id is always ***unique***, if you want to reuse it use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to put the paragraphs inside the link tag.
 The paragraph tag has some margin by default which makes the navigation bar higher.
  Also the unordered list has margin by default which makes it even more higher.
  So the easiest way would be to remove the paragraph tag.
  Even if that's not enough you can remove the margin of the unordered list.
  Take a look at this JSFiddle:

```css
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    //font-family: lkth;
    border: double;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #663D07;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#navLi {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
/* #navUl {
    margin: 0;
} */

/* If thats not enought you can uncomment the above code */
.navA {
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navUl">
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#">Page d'accueil</a></li>
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#">Evénements</a></li>
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#">Contactez nous</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```